# Replacing Font Awesome in heading with local SVG

Tags: svg

I'm using this snippet for adding a Font Awesome icon in front of H1 headings:

```
h1:before {
   content: "\f192  ";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

How to adapt it for using a locally served (on site's server) SVG icon instead?
(that is uploaded in WP Media Library and using SVG Support plugin)

Answer (score 2):

If your icon needs to remain a separate file, you can set it as a background image.

```
h1:before {
   display: inline-block;
   background-image: url(resources/icon.svg)
}
```

Otherwise you can embed your icon as a data url.

```
h1:before {
   display: inline-block;
   background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,...etc...)
}
```

**Update**

Working example:

```css
h1:before {
   content: " ";
   display: inline-block;
   width: 0.7em;
   height: 0.7em;
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 10'%3E%3Ccircle cx='5' cy='5' r='5'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a title</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks but don't well understand how to use the URL values in parenthesis.
The closest I got is with this but the icon displays on TOP of the H1 title and not before on same line:
---

h1:before {
content: " ";
display: block;
height: 60px;
background: url("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/test.svg")no-repeat;
}
---

Comment: `didplay: inline-block` should work.  Otherwise you can just add some left padding to the H1 in order to leave space for the overlaid icon.

Comment: Tried this but padding gets added to both, the icon and the title.

Comment: That's true. But you can give the `:before` a negative margin to move it back out again.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: I've update my answer with a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much that works fine now indeed.
The only problem is that the SVG displays smaller than the title and with my previous working snippet I had "height: 60px" that was giving a correct size to it.
Now, with "em" it works great in terms of positioning related to the title but the size is too small...
I tried increasing those sizes in there but I'm loosing the relative position to the title.

Comment: Currently the SVG is sits on the text baseline due to the use of `display: inline-block`.  That's normally what people want.  If you want something different, you are probably going to need to explain it in a new question.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I'll keep it that way for now, thanks a lot.